# How to set routing between two countries? Load two “*-gh” folders

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

I want to get route between two neighborhood countries, I converted pbf files to grapphopper format:

```
./graphhopper.sh -a import -i germany.osm.pbf
./graphhopper.sh -a import -i moldova.osm.pbf
```

But when I try to load those countries I get next error:

```
GraphHopper graphHopper = new GraphHopper().forMobile();
graphHopper.load(new File(mOSMData, "germany-gh").getAbsolutePath());
graphHopper.load(new File(mOSMData, "moldova-gh").getAbsolutePath());
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: graph is already successfully loaded
>           at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.load(GraphHopper.java:725)

Is there any solution for that or **GraphHopper** can work only with one OSM data at the same time and there is no way to connect two countries or two cities if there are different folders?

Comment: I guess you can only load one graph, thus you need to merge the PBF files before.

Comment: @scai yes, I see such problem isn't solved yet https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/293

Comment: Cross-posted https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-set-routing-between-two-countries-load-two-gh-folders/3822

Comment: This is not possible with graphhopper. I am using osmconver to merge my pbf files to one and load that one into graphhopper. In the link below you can see an example. You'll also see an example of osmium which can do the same. https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48843/merging-two-or-more-geographical-areas-to-import-two-or-more-osm-files-in-nominatim